# Xamarin Forms How can I use ListView for show string[] which is part of the same JSON response that show inside a CarouselView?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

All the fields show ok, only Specilities string[] shows me an error... remember there are two different fids on json response we have Speciality that is OK and show OK... and we have Specilities string[] where is the problem.... check the json response

this is json response

```
{"_id":"5aab4c02f08d9324fc1283ec","firstName":"Carlos Alberto","lastName":"Cabezas Delgado","password":"$2a$10$BuYWhiMn.9RsBKJN7bWuguKaPAHQocd2eVQCqRaaAdmzrlPkuWYJS","identificationNumber":"0914891684","email":"carlos.cabezas@abogadosecuador.com.ec","phone":"0969922421","discount":0.5,"band":3,"city":"59cda262fe728437ce90ff81","role":"59cd270f07308946e6a494f7","__v":6,


"speciality":{"_id":"5a0a6176257e970afc9a9e7f","name":"Propiedad Intelectual","tag":"propiedad-intelectual","__v":0,"icon":"speciality_icon_jg4zpoeqoiwtuuy8jya.png","description":"Derechos de propiedad industrial, derechos de autor, patentes, modelos de utilidad, diseños industriales, marcas, indicaciones geográficas, información comercial confidencial, derecho de obtentor.","id":"5a0a6176257e970afc9a9e7f"},

"profile":"5aac7b42c02ece25becefd47","telephone":"593969922421","createdAt":"2018-08-20T03:07:03.838Z","searchTag":"CARLOSALBERTOCABEZASDELGADO","updatedAt":"2020-06-22T00:17:30.971Z","label":"CARLOS ALBERTO CABEZAS DELGADO","firstNameLabel":"Carlos Alberto","lastNameLabel":"Cabezas Delgado","plan":"5d75e792184bab2c72b3d3ab","seller":"5ad72ce8fd69e7aba867c118","telephone2":"","fax":"593969922421","isPublic":true,"isDelete":false,
"invoices":[],


"specialities":["5990d7273da48f4bd98c6918","5990d73f3da48f4bd98c691a","5a0a6055257e970afc9a9e70","5a0a6087257e970afc9a9e73","5a0a6120257e970afc9a9e7a","5a0a6166257e970afc9a9e7e","5a0a6176257e970afc9a9e7f"],


"location":{"address":"Urbanización Puerto Azul, Guayaquil, Ecuador","reference":"Puerto Azul, Vía la Costa (Edificio Torres del Edén)","latitude":-2.1902934315119,"longitude":-79.9647494058045},"status":2,"id":"5aab4c02f08d9324fc1283ec","search":"CARLOS ALBERTO CABEZAS DELGADO"
```

MODEL DATA

```
namespace App1

{




    public class AbogadosMongoApi
    {


        [JsonProperty("_id")]
        public string Idab { get; set; }




        [JsonProperty("label")]
        public string FirtsName { get; set; }


        [JsonProperty("email")]
        public string Correo { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("phone")]
        public string Celular { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("password")]


        public string Contrasena { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("isPublic")]
        public bool Public { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("band")]
        public int Band { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("plan")]
        public string Plan { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("city")]
        public string Ciudadperfil { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("location")]

        public Location location { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("speciality")]

        public Speciality speciality { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("specialities")]

        public string[] Specialities { get; set; }

       
    }

    public class Speciality
    {


        [JsonProperty("_id")]
        public string Idespecialidad { get; set; }


        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Nombrespecialidad { get; set; }


        [JsonProperty("icon")]
        public string Iconespecialidad { get; set; }



        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Descespecialidad { get; set; }
    }




    public class Location
    {


        [JsonProperty("address")]
        public string Direccion { get; set; }


        [JsonProperty("reference")]
        public string Referencia { get; set; }


        [JsonProperty("latitude")]
        public string Latitud { get; set; }



        [JsonProperty("longitude")]
        public string Longitud { get; set; }
    }



}
```

---

XAML

```
    <CollectionView x:Name="abogadosrec"
                            BackgroundColor="#eee"
                            SelectionMode="Single"
                                SelectionChanged="CallBtnClicked"
                                VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <SwipeView>
                                <SwipeView.LeftItems>
                                    <SwipeItems>
                                       
                                    </SwipeItems>
                                </SwipeView.LeftItems>
                                <SwipeView.RightItems>
                                    <SwipeItems>
                                        <SwipeItem Text="Crear Cita"
                                                   
                                                   BackgroundColor="#00a783" />
                                       
                                    </SwipeItems>
                                </SwipeView.RightItems>
                                <Grid Style="{StaticResource IndicatorLabelStyle}"
                                      Padding="20">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Frame CornerRadius="100"
                                           HeightRequest="75"
                                           WidthRequest="75"
                                           BorderColor="#cca876"
                                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                           Padding="0"
                                           IsClippedToBounds="True">
                                        <Image  xct:TouchEffect.PressedScale="1.4"
                                                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                                Source="{Binding Idab, StringFormat='https://abogadosecuador.com.ec/profile/picture/{0:N}'}"
                                                Aspect="AspectFill"
                                                HeightRequest="75"
                                                WidthRequest="75" />
                                    </Frame>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                                           Text="{Binding FirtsName}"
                                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                           HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                           FontSize="Micro"
                                       FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding .}"
                                          HasUnevenRows="true">
                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ViewCell>
                                                <Label FontSize="3" Text="{Binding Specialities}"></Label>
                                            </ViewCell>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListView>
                                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                                           x:Name="txtNumero" IsVisible="false"
                                           Text="{Binding Celular, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                           FontAttributes="Italic"
                                           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                       HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                                
                               
                                </Grid>
                            </SwipeView>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <CollectionView.Header>
                        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightGray">
                            <Label Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                   Padding="10"
                                   Text="Abogados Registrados"
                                   FontSize="Small" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </CollectionView.Header>
                </CollectionView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding .}"
```

should be

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Specialities}"
```

and this

```
<Label FontSize="3" Text="{Binding Specialities}" />
```

should be

```
<Label FontSize="3" Text="{Binding .}" />
```

Comment: not show error, but not show information on test app.. only blank like nothing is present on screen... the other fields on caroselview show OK... this my api call

Comment: async void Premium_Abogados(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {


            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var resultJson = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("URL");

            var resultAbogados = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AbogadosMongoApi[]>(resultJson);   abogadosrec.ItemsSource = resultAbogados.Where(d => d.Plan == "5d75e770184bab2c72b3d3aa").Where(d => d.Public == true).ToList();

        }

Comment: I had a typo in how I spelled "Specialities", please be sure that yours is correct.  And [edit] your question to add additional code, do not just stuff it into a comment

Comment: sorry i do the corrections... im new here

Comment: yo are amazing 100/100 , thanks... i have other question... let me contact u